# Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded..disable and checked not woorking

Tags: javascript

I am working on j query..recently updated from 1.9 o v3.0 and this is one of the issues.the code is not unchecking the options..Can't find proper solution.

```
function unCheck(checkBoxControl) {
  if (checkBoxControl.is(':checked')) {
    checkBoxControl.attr('checked', false);
    checkBoxControl.change(); // issue here
  }
}

$('#divSccCrimAuthDigital input[type=checkbox]').change(function() {
    if($(this).is(':checked')) {  //issue here
      unCheck($('#divSccCriminelCan input[type=checkbox]'));
      unCheck($('#divSccCriminelAuth input[type=checkbox]'));
      unCheck($('#divSccDigitalAuth input[type=checkbox]'));
    }
    if(typeof setEmailValidator === 'function') {
      setEmailValidator($(this).is(':checked'));
    }
    if(typeof setCandidatWorkflow === 'function') {
      setCandidatWorkflow($(this).is(':checked'));
    }
  });

function unCheck(checkBoxControl) {
  if (checkBoxControl.is(':checked')) {
    checkBoxControl.attr('checked', false);
    checkBoxControl.change();
  }
}

function setGenericValidator(elemid, onoff) {
  var validateur = document.getElementById(elemid);
  if(validateur && typeof ValidatorEnable === 'function')
    ValidatorEnable(validateur, onoff);
}

function disableExtraTab() {
  if($('#divAutresVerif input[type=checkbox]:checked').length == 0) {
    $('#divTabz').tabs( { disabled: [1,2] } );
  }
  else {
    $('#divTabz').tabs( { disabled: [] } );//issue here
  }
}
```

In console i am getting this error.

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (Rapport.aspx:274)
    at HTMLInputElement.dispatch (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.y.handle (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Object.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at Function.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.each (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.trigger (jquery-3.3.1.min.js:2)
    at w.fn.init.w.fn.(anonymous function) [as change] 
    at unCheck (Rapport.aspx:337)
```

i cant find out whats wrong.worked fine before the upgrade.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct way to set `checked` is to use [`prop`](https://api.jquery.com/prop/), not [`attr`](https://api.jquery.com/attr/). `attr` used to have a list of things it would defer to `prop`, but at some point that was removed and modern jQuery requires you to use the correct method. (I don't see this in the v3 release notes, though there's [something closely related](https://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/3.0/#attributes).) So since the change isn't happening, and since `unCheck` triggers `change` handlers, you end up in an endless loop.

Switching to `prop` fixes it.

Live example with `attr` that fails:

```js
function unCheck(cb) {
  if (cb.is(":checked")) {
    cb.attr("checked", false);
    cb.change();
  }
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        unCheck($($(this).attr("data-other")));
    }
});
```

```html
Mutually-exclusive checkboxes: Check the first, then check the second, and the first should get unchecked. (But in this version, you'll get a stack ovreflow error.)
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cb1" data-other="#cb2" type="checkbox">
    Checkbox 1
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cb2" data-other="#cb1" type="checkbox">
    Checkbox 2
  </label>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Live example with `prop` that works:

```js
function unCheck(cb) {
  if (cb.is(":checked")) {
    cb.prop("checked", false);
    cb.change();
  }
}
$("input[type=checkbox]").on("change", function() {
    if (this.checked) {
        unCheck($($(this).attr("data-other")));
    }
});
```

```html
Mutually-exclusive checkboxes: Check the first, then check the second, and the first should get unchecked.
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cb1" data-other="#cb2" type="checkbox">
    Checkbox 1
  </label>
</div>
<div>
  <label>
    <input id="cb2" data-other="#cb1" type="checkbox">
    Checkbox 2
  </label>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

But I'd seriously rethink having `unCheck` trigger `change` handlers. In general, synthetically triggering standard UI events is (IMHO) an anti-pattern. Instead, isolate the logic you want to use into a function, and call that function directly (and also, as appropriate, in response to the event).

---

Side note: You have two copies of `unCheck` there. Only the second is being used. I'd remove the first, although on first glance they're identical.

Side note 2: `$(this).is(':checked')` is a really long-winded way to write `this.checked`. There's no reason to create a jQuery object and then call a function that has to parse a CSS selector, when you can just look directly at the property.

Comment: Can one use `checkBoxControl.checked = whatever` ?

Comment: @Seblor - If `checkBoxControl` were a DOM element, yes. But it's a jQuery object (a wrapper around zero or more DOM elements [or sometimes other things]), not a DOM element.